# How to add excel range as a picture to outlook message body

Tags: excel, vba, image, outlook, sendmail

I'd like to build\edit the mail signiture in Excel:

```
1st cell        : |Regards,      |
2nd cell (Name) : |Asaf Gilad    |
3rd Cell (Title): |PMO           |
4th cell (Mail) : |Asaf@mail.com |
```

So that when I click send, the body of the message will look like:

```
Dear sir
................................
....... Message Content ........
................................
................................

Regards,
Asaf Gilad    
PMO           
Asaf@mail.com
```

The signiture contains pictures as well.

I managed to save the range as picture and send that picture as attachment, but the picture turned out to be empty in the body, dispite the fact that it was sent correctly as attachment.

Here is the code I use:

```
Public Sub ExportEmail(recipentName As String)
    On Error GoTo err:
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim olNs As Outlook.Namespace
    Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim strEmailTo As String, strEmailCC As String, strEmailBCC As String 
    Dim FNAME As String
    Dim oRange As Range
    Dim oChart As Chart
    Dim oImg As Picture
    strEmailTo = ""
    strEmailCC = ""
    strEmailBCC = ""
    strEmailTo = "a@a.com"
    strEmailCC = "b@b.com
    If strEmailTo  "" Then
        Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
        Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
        olNs.Logon
        Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
        olMail.To = strEmailTo
        olMail.CC = strEmailCC
        olMail.BCC = strEmailBCC
        olMail.Subject = " My Subject"
        Set oRange = Sheets(1).Range("A1:Z100") 
        Set oChart = Charts.Add
        oRange.CopyPicture xlScreen, xlPicture
        oChart.Paste
        FNAME = Environ$("temp") & "\testPic.gif"
        oChart.Export Filename:=FNAME, FilterName:="GIF"
        olMail.Attachments.Add FNAME
        olMail.HTMLBody = "" & _
            ""
        olMail.Attachments.Add FNAME
        olMail.Send
    End If
    Application.StatusBar = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Kill FNAME
    Set olApp = Nothing
    Set olNs = Nothing
    Set oRange = Nothing
    Set oChart = Nothing
    Set oImg = Nothing
    Exit Sub
err:
    MsgBox err.Description
End Sub
```

Comment: why do you want to create signature adding programme when Outlook already has that wizard to add a signature easily?

Comment: I'm not sure yet. The customer defined this need. Maybe he wants emails sent by my tool to be signed differently than other mails. It's a good idea to ask him for the reason, nevertheless I find this excel-outlook task interesting. Beside the current task it may help me automate some mail composing (can't think of good example: maybe report summary)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good question, Asaf. When I have built automated e-mail solutions, I've found it difficult to get the signature line in. It's possible, but not easy. Maybe it's updated in 2010, but I haven't checked yet.

What I do is place the entire body into a text file on a drive, complete with any html tags that I want for formatting. This gives me great flexibility in both making nicely formatted e-mails where I can assign variables as well.

I then access those files through the `Microsoft Scripting Runtime` library.

See below code snippets:

```
Option Explicit

Const strEmailBoiler As String = "\\server\path\folder\subfolder\email_text\"

Sub PrepMessage()

Dim strBody As String, strMon As String

strMon = range("Mon").Value
strFY = range("FY").Value
strBody = FileToString(strEmailBoiler, "reports_email_body.txt")

strBody = Replace(strBody, "[MONTH]", strMon)
strBody = Replace(strBody, "[YEAR]", Right(strFY, 2))
strBody = Replace(strBody, "[FILE PATH]", strFileName)

SendMail "firstname.lastname@xyz.com", "Subject Goes Here " & strMon & " YTD", strBody

End Sub

Function FileToString(ByVal strPath As String, ByVal strFile As String) As String
'requires reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime Object Library (or late binding)

    Dim ts As TextStream

    Set fso = New FileSystemObject
    Set ts = fso.OpenTextFile(strPath & strFile, ForReading, False, TristateUseDefault)

    FileToString = ts.ReadAll
    ts.Close

    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing

End Function

Sub SendMail(strTo As String, strSubject As String, strHTMLBody As String, Optional strAttach As String, Optional strCC As String)
'requires reference to Microsoft Outlook X.X Object Library (or late binding)

Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olMI As Outlook.MailItem

Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set olMI = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

With olMI

    .To = strTo
    .Subject = strSubject
    .HTMLBody = strHTMLBody
    If strAttach <> vbNullString Then .Attachments.Add strAttach
    .Display 'using this because of security access to Outlook
    '.Send

End With

End Sub
```

Then my `reports_email_body.txt` file will look like this:

```
<p>Hello Person,</p> 
<p>The Reports file for [MONTH] FY[YEAR] has been saved in the following location:</p>
<p><a href="[FILE PATH]">[FILE PATH]</a></p>
<p>Best,</p>
<br>
Scott Holtzman
<br>My Address
<br>my title
<br>whatever else...
```

Answer (score 1):

In Excel 2010 (and possibly 2007) you can add .HTMLBody to the end of your body string.  For instance, use something like this:

```
    .HTMLBody = "<br>" & strbody & .HTMLBody
                ' <br> is an HTML tag to turn the text into HTML
                ' strbody is your text from cell C9 on the mail tab
                ' .HTMLBody inserts your email signature
```

This will at least solve your signature line problem.

I am looking for a solution for the same problem: Inserting a range as a picture.